# Flutter AndroidView Widget

Tags: java, android, flutter

Rendering CameraX API With AndroidView in flutter cause the app to render the native widget ontop of the flutter app, the new widget covers the flutter debug banner, even in a stack, no other widget is rendered because it will be covered by a native widget. this issue occurs when CameraX is loaded fully

The project: https://github.com/wanoghoco/camerapreview

Answer (score 2):

My solution is to downgrade to flutter 2.10.5.